# Javax @Valid Annotation in Inner NEsted Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I want to use javax validation on poco objects that contain complex types. In my code, I want to validate the `PersonDetail` object inside my `Person` class. If I don't use the `@Valid PersonDetail`, then validations on that subclass don't work.

Is there any way to validate nested objects without the `@Valid` annotation on each one?

```
public class Person {


@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]+$")
private String surname;

@Valid(//without this personDetails validations not worked)
    private PersonDetail personDetail;
```

....

PersonDetail class

```
public class PersonDetail {

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]+$")
    private String surname2;

    public String getSurname2() {
        return surname2;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you need `@Valid` on the `personDetail` field in order for validation to continue to look down into that field. You can configure this in other ways (validation.xml), but ultimately you need to tell the Validator to descend into the value of the `personDetail` field.